# How do I find a Lava Charm?

Tags: terraria, terraria-mobile

I'm trying to make Lava Waders in Terraria, and I'm not quite sure how to find a lava charm. On the wikia page it says to look near the lava underground layer, and I did, but I can't find one! Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Lava Charm](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Lava_Charm) can occasionally be found as an item within gold chests in the [Cavern layer](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Cavern). As with most things in Terraria, the contents of chests are randomized, so there's no guarantee your world will have one of these items. Using Spelunker Potions to find chests is about as good as you'll do; you just have to hope one of them contains this accessory.

Answer (score 0):

You find them in one of those wooden structures in a cavern layer. They're pretty rare though. I've found 2 out of many many worlds.

Comment: Do you mean underground cabins?